# How do I get SQL to generate an XML file while limiting the possible results to only that user's data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, security

I have a SQL database with thousands of user's information. This db is not exposed to users of course. I am tasked with finding a way to get the SQL db to generate an XML file from a query to be used as a data source for reporting. However, I must do it in such a way that only the logged-in user's data is accessible to them (users must not be able to see each other's data).

Any assistance greatly appreciated!

  -

Comment: `SELECT *  FROM tblName
FOR XML PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Use `FOR XML`

Ref :

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178107.aspx
2. http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/
3. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

**HINT :** Select data which are related to the logged user. something like below,

```
Select * from .... Where user = ''
```